# How IONIC NavController works, when nav.push components?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

i have 3 pages in my Ionic 3:

*first page* : a tabs page which contains a list of articles.

*second page*: contains information detail of article and a button that will fire third page for commenting the article.

*third page* : contains a field for comment and a button to submit data to API Server.

the problem is i use navController.push to redirect back to the tabs page (first page) later user submitted the comment and after user commented like 5 articles my ionic application gets more more slow and crash. it really slows to open second page.

i assume that it because of navController.push, if user commented 5 articles n redirected back to first page it means that it will be like 5 stack of component in the stack list.

my question is NavController.push performs by reference or not? and what does make my application slow?

IONIC 3

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

1. Look at the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/navigation/NavController/), nav controller has `pop` and `popToRoot` methods
2. Each time you push it will create new instance, but even 5 pages in the stack is nothing so probably you have some listeners in code with heavy logic
3. Look at Lifecycle events, specially in your root page you will probably need to implement `ionViewWillEnter` to reload articles